# store result of query and use in another query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store the result of one query $sql and use this result in the second query $sql1.

$sql selects the value in the column clear and should store this in $result.

$sql1 should update the column that is found from $sql and switch the value of that column to NOT $result, boolean column.

The reason I need this is because the column I am updating depends on the value of column clear, which contains the names of various columns. These columns are also all in the same table.

```
<?php

$userIdentity = $_SESSION['userIdentity'];

$sql = "SELECT clear FROM UserInfo WHERE userIdentity = '$userIdentity'";

$result = $dbc->query($sql); 

$sql1 ="UPDATE UserInfo SET $result = NOT $result WHERE userIdentity = '$userIdentity'";

$result1 = $dbc->query($sql1); 

?>
```

Comment: do a foreach on the first result.. and get the values to be updated.

Comment: No. Just use 1 query

Comment: What is $dbc? Is this a PDO object?

Comment: $dbc is used to connect to the database in a separate file.

Comment: Yes, but what is it? How are you creating it? The answer is going to depend on what kind of object $dbc is.

Comment: I am new to php so I am not sure what the name of it is but here is the code for the connection to the database

Comment: $dbc = @mysqli_connect ( 'localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name' )

OR die ( mysqli_connect_error() ) ;


mysqli_set_charset( $dbc, 'utf8' ) ;

Comment: Can you remove either the MySQL or SQL-Server tag.  These are different products.  Knowing which RDBMS you are using will ensure you recieve a answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$dbc` is a `mysqli` object, [mysqli::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object on a successful query. This means that `$result` is not going to be the single value you expect it to be; instead, it's going to be an object that represents the entire response to the query.

You will want to do something like this to actually get the value of your `clear` column:

```
$result = $dbc->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_object(); //get the first row from the result
$clear = $row->clear;
```

You can then use `$clear` to update your database in the second query. (You can't easily do this in one query because the column you are modifying depends on the value of a row in the database. Doing this in entirely in one query may be possible, but is probably also more trouble than it's worth.)

Caveats:

- If the query returns no rows, $row will be null. So you will need to check for this.
- Note that you do have a potential SQL injection vulnerability by passing `$clear` and `$userIdentity` directly into the sql query. For `$userIdentity`, you should use parameterized queries (which means you can't use `mysqli::query()`; see [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for an example of how to do this). Since `$clear` is used as a column name, and you can't parameterize column names, you will need to take extra care to ensure that it is valid.

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm. Also thanks for the Caveats I will implement these as well